# "Could not connect to Apple servers with this certificate" on parse.com for Push Notifications

Tags: ios, parse-platform, openssl, certificate

I'm trying to create a .p12 certificate via OpenSSL for Apple Push Services which I want to upload on parse.com for a certain app.

The steps I followed:

1. Generate .csr file via Intel XDK (before building the app).
2. Upload .csr file in developer.apple.com for Push Notifications for the certain app.
3. Download the .cer file that is generated after uploading the .csr file.

**At this point, the problems start.**

I find instructions to generate .p12 via Keychain Access on Mac, but I am working on Windows.

I tried to generate the .p12 file by using **OpenSSL** and I ran the following commands:

1. openssl x509 -in aps.cer -inform DER -out aps.pem -outform PEM
2. openssl req -x509 -nodes -days 365 -newkey rsa:2048 -keyout aps.key -out aps.pem
3. openssl pkcs12 -export -out aps.p12 -inkey aps.key -in aps.pem

Then I attempted to upload the .p12 file on parse.com but the following error occured:

**Unsupported certificate type. Common Name (CN) must contain one of: Apple Production IOS Push Services, Apple Push Services, Apple Development IOS Push Services, Pass Type ID, Apple Development Mac Push Services, Apple Production Mac Push Services.**

Then, I attempted while running the 2nd command on OpenSSL (the one for generating the private key), to insert as Common Name (CN) "Apple Push Services". After that, I generated the .p12 again (3rd command).

Then, I attempted to upload the .p12 file on parse.com again, but now another error occurs:

**Could not connect to Apple servers with this certificate.**

I am not an OpenSSL expert, so does anyone know if there is anything wrong with the commands above?

Could there be any simpler way to generate .p12 certificate on Windows?

Or are there any special settings that I should take under consideration while I generate the private key? I am not sure what the Common Name (CN) should be.